# Trouble with developing product order creation on a Spring/AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, spring

I'm currently developing an order management system. The systems back-end is developed using the Spring Framework and the front-end is developed using AngularJS. 
I'm having some trouble with correctly programming the order creation. The orders are pretty complex. Involving multiple parts:
– Products
– Custom text (this can be added on the product during production)
– Specific location (these locations are in the database and there should be a possibility to add extra info on the order)

Currently I'm building the order up in Angular and send it to the server as one object. The calculations of the order are done in AngularJS to be displayed on the front-end. The object send to the server does not include these results. final calculations are done on the back-end. So yes the Angular calc are just for show.

Now this is where my problem is. (if it even is a problem, I'm not completely sure.)
It should never happen that the price is different on the front-end than after saving the order.

Could someone give me some advice on how to properly implement this.

Do you think it's a good idea to create the order using Angular and then send it as a complete object to save it in the DB?
Or should I just create a blank order and add products using calls to the server?

Maybe some other suggestions?

Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Never trust something coming from the frontend. You really don't want anyone sending a JSON with a fake small price. If you really want the price to be the one computed by the backend, and are not confident about the correctness of the frontend computation, then ask the server to always compute the price, using an AJAX request.

Comment: That was actually the reason why I did the final computation on the backend. So the order object only contains the products and quantity. Now if I send a request to calculate the price on the backend. Would you consider just creating an order in the DB and then add each product per request. This seems to get pretty bloated in my eyes. And we'll prob end up with some empty/half-filled orders which I would like to avoid. If I do a call to just calculate I will get a really complex call to the server. Maybe someone has dealt with this before??

Comment: I don't know enough of your problem to understand what you mean. Not sure why you would have to persist anything just to compute a price.